# Making a toolbar dynamic on resize XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a toolbar that I want to have its items stack on top of each other as the window resizes (Like as if its within a Bootstrap grid if it was HTML)...

```
<Grid  VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="TopBar"  Margin="0,0,0.35,0" Opacity="0.8">  
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <textbox Grid.Column="0" content="text"/>
    <ToolBarPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="500"> 
            <Button content="toolbar_item"></Button>
            <Button content="toolbar_item"></Button>
            <Button content="toolbar_item"></Button>
             <Button content="toolbar_item"></Button>
            <Button content="toolbar_item"></Button>
            <Button content="toolbar_item"></Button>
        </WrapPanel>
    </ToolBarPanel>
</Grid>
```

However under this setting the buttons stack on load but they arn't dynamic, they don't continue to stack as the window gets smaller they just overflow. Is there a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. The effect you're saying can be achieved by using a `ViewBox`. Please check below code.

```
<Grid  VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="TopBar"  Margin="0,0,0.35,0" Opacity="0.8">
    <Viewbox>
        <ToolBarPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <WrapPanel>
                <Button Content="toolbar_item"></Button>
            <Button Content="toolbar_item"></Button>
            <Button Content="toolbar_item"></Button>
            <Button Content="toolbar_item"></Button>
            <Button Content="toolbar_item"></Button>
            <Button Content="toolbar_item"></Button>
        </WrapPanel>
    </ToolBarPanel>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: using Viewbox made the buttons smaller/larger on resize but it didn't really stack them on top of each other. I wanted to keep the buttons at the same size, just make the column width get smaller on resize, allowing the buttons to overflow vertically and stack, if that makes sense. I've updated the code the include the grid columns I have set up, not sure if it makes a difference.

Comment: I don’t think that is possible. Since the orientation of your toolbar is horizontal, you can’t expect such kind of automatically resizing and stacking in opposite orientation.
If it’s very much required, I think you may need to write the logic, i.e. while resizing occurs beyond a certain limit, change the orientation to vertical and stack them manually.

Comment: yeah sure, I'll have to do some kind of work around. Thanks for the help anyway though!